# Таймер обратного отсчёта на JavaScript на секунду показывает неправильные денные для отсчёта

Tags: jquery, javascript

При загрузке таймера (http://jsfiddle.net/victorpavloff/u9fz4/) на пол секунды показывается другой период для отсчёта. Какую бы дату для начала отсчёта и какой интервал бы я не задавал, на секунду появляется следующее: 3 дня: 21 час: 44 минуты: 13 секунд. А потом уже нужные данные для отсчёта. Можно ли как-то решить эту проблему?

Comment: Вы шутите? У вас же в html это прописано изначально. Вам надо всего лишь [почистить][1] его? ))

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/u9fz4/3/

Comment: @Виктор Павлов а что вам мешает взять и убрать эти начальные значения, жестко прописанные в html?

Comment: Вот я дурак! :-) Заказал просто этот скрипт у фрилансера, а на дивы не посмотрел даже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Было:

`<div id="timer1">
  <div id="days">
    <div class="left">0</div>
    <div class="right">3</div>
...`

Замени все цифры на `&nbsp;`. Должно получиться примерно так:

`<div id="timer1">
  <div id="days">
    <div class="left">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="right">&nbsp;</div>
...`

и так далее.
Дальше сам =)

Comment: Да, со зрением у меня плоховато :-) Не заметил цыфры в дивах :-)